# ¿Cómo solucionar el error Could not parse some characters?

Tags: html, python, django

Este es el error

> TemplateSyntaxError at /curso/7/diagnostico/ Could not parse some
> characters:
> request.POST.get|('pregunta'||add:pregunta.id|stringformat:"s", '')

Este es la parte del html que manda error

```
<div>
  {% for pregunta in preguntas %}
    <li style="color: grey;">
      Pregunta: {{ pregunta.cuerpo }}<br>
      Respuesta del usuario: {{ request.POST.get('pregunta'|add:pregunta.id|stringformat:"s", '') }}<br>
      Alternativa correcta: {{ respuestas_contexto.get(pregunta.id|stringformat:"s").alternativa_correcta|default:'' }}<br>
      Evaluación: {{ respuestas_contexto.get(pregunta.id|stringformat:"s").evaluacion|default:'' }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

y esta es la vista de ese template

```
def diag_curso(request, curso_id):
   curso = Cursos.objects.get(id=curso_id)
   preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(curso_id=curso_id)
   context = {'curso': curso, 'preguntas': preguntas}

   if request.method == 'POST':
       respuestas_usuario = {}
       for clave, valor in request.POST.items():
           if empiezapregunta(clave):
               clave_limpia = quitarpregdeclave(clave)
               respuestas_usuario[clave_limpia] = valor

       alternativa_correcta = obtener_respuestas_correctas(curso_id)
       evaluaciones = {}

       for clave, respuesta in respuestas_usuario.items():
           pregunta_id = clave[4:]  # Eliminar el prefijo 'preg_'
           evaluaciones[pregunta_id] = respuesta == alternativa_correcta.get(pregunta_id)

       respuestas_contexto = {}
       for pregunta in preguntas:
           pregunta_id = str(pregunta.id)
           respuestas_contexto[pregunta_id] = {
               'respuesta_usuario': respuestas_usuario.get(pregunta_id, ''),
               'alternativa_correcta': alternativa_correcta.get(pregunta_id, ''),
               'evaluacion': 'Correcta' if evaluaciones.get(pregunta_id, False) else 'Incorrecta'
           }

       context['respuestas_contexto'] = respuestas_contexto

   return render(request, 'curso_diag.html', context)
```

Le he dado muchas vueltas, he cambiado muchas cosas y sigue... logro que desaparezca el error, pero no logro hacer que haga lo que pretendo que haga.

Si alguien me puede ayudar con esto.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes.  Con qué dato de prueba se genera ese error?
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).